# The partial fraction expansion of $\frac{1}{\cos z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

According to the Mittag-Leffler partial fraction expansion theorem for meromorphic functons, $$
\frac{1}{\cos z}= 1+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\Big (\frac{1}{z-\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n}+\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n}\Big). $$

But how does one rearrange terms (and justify the rearrangement) to show that  $$\frac{1}{\cos z}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{z^{2}-(\frac{2n+1}{2})^{2}\pi^2} \ ? $$

**EDIT**:

An alternative version of the theorem (which requires showing that $\int \frac{\sec w}{w-z} \ dw$ vanishes around an appropriate contour) allows one to conclude that

$$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{\cos z} &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{z - \frac{\pi}{2}- \pi n} \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{(-n-1)+1}}{z - \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi (-n-1)} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{z - \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi n} \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \left( \frac{-1}{z+ \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n} + \frac{1}{z- \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi n} \right) \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n+1) \pi}{z^{2}- (\frac{2n+1}{2})^{2}\pi^{2}}. \end{align}$$

Comment: See [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB) starting on page $104$.

Comment: Thanks for the link to your paper. I didn't know about the more general form of the theorem.

Comment: Good that you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** 
Let
$$a_n = (-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{z-\pi/2-n\pi} + \frac{1}{\pi/2+n\pi}\right).$$
Notice that $a_n = O(1/n^2)\, (n\to\infty)$ and that 
$$a_n + a_{-n-1} = (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{z^2-\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2}
+ (-1)^{n+1}\frac{4}{(2n+1)\pi}.$$

Comment: So $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{-n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_{n}+a_{-n-1}) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \Big( \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{z^2-\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2} + \frac{4}{(2n+1)\pi} \Big) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{z^2-\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2} - \frac{4}{\pi} \arctan(1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{z^2-\left(\frac{2n+1}{2}\right)^2\pi^2} -1 ?$$

Comment: @RandomVariable: Looks good.

Comment: What is the significance of the behavior of $a_{n}$ at infinity?

Comment: @RandomVariable: It justifies the rearrangement $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n+a_{-n-1})$. At present I can't justify the second rearrangement (leading to the final result).

Answer (score 2):

The terms in
$\Big (\frac{1}{z-\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n}+\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n}\Big)$
are not absolutely convergent,
since
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{z-\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi n}$
diverges.

So you may have problems.